# Directly proof $S$ is countable, where $S$ is set of function from $\{0, 1\}$ to $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers, elementary-functions, first-countable

Suppose $S=\{f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4,f_5,........\}$ where $f_i$ is a function $f:\{0, 1\}\to\mathbb{N}.$ I have to prove $S$ is countable.Then need to prove direct one-to-one correspondence between $S$ and $\mathbb{N}.$ If I put $(\{0,f(0)\},\{1,f(1)\})=(\{0,1\},\{1,1\})$ for $f_1$ map to $1,$
Similarly,$(\{0,2\},\{1,2\})$ for $f_2$ map to $2..................$$(\{0,i\},\{1,i\})$ for $f_i$ map to $i...............$

Is it showing direct bijection between $S$ and $\mathbb{N}.$ But I already  proven $S$ is countable by **Countability Lemma.** I need to understand why my direct proof concept is wrong.

Comment: Hint: give a bijection from the set of such function to $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Slugger I already proven S is countable.. Where is the problem for proving directly? I have mention in my question.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net the set of maps from $\{0,1\}$ to $\Bbb N$ is quite countable, it's $\aleph_0^2$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks for taking me out of my nap... I deleted my wrong comment.

Comment: @Henno right.. I already proven by Counting Lemma.. Where is the problem for proving directly?

Comment: You don't give a bijection. What is the Countability Lemma?

Comment: @Henno **Countability Lemma:** Suppose to each element of the set $S$ there is assigned, by some definite rule, a unique natural number in such a manner that to each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there corresponds at most finite number of elelments of the set $S.$ Then $S$ is countable.

Comment: @Henno I already proven by lemma $(\{0,a\},\{1,b\})=a+b$

Comment: I suggest max below but sum also works (but needs a small argument).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list of functions is incomplete: $\{(0,i), (1,i)\}$ is a constant function, but there are also functions like $\{(0,564), (1, 876)\}$; where do you map those, i.e. what number do *they* get?

If you want to use the countability lemma you state in the comments, you can: just assign $\max(f(0), f(1))$ to $\{(0,f(0)), (1,f(1)\} \in S$ then there are at most finitely many functions with assigned value $n$ for each $n$ (why?)..

Comment: every n is finite, we can easily count

Comment: @User4567 More precisely it's $2(n+1) - 1 = 2n+1$ for each $n$.

Comment: give one example for $(2n+1)$ for each $n.$

Comment: The max could be $f(0)$ in $n+1$ ways, $n+1$ ways for it to be $f(1)$ and $-1$ for the constant map that's counted doubly. @User4567

Comment: what is n here?

Comment: @User4567 the assigned value, as in your lemma.

Comment: @User4567 for $n=3$ we get $(0,3)$ combined with one of  $(1,0),\ldots,(1,3)$ to get $4$ options etc.

Comment: You take $0\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @User4567 Of course $0 \in \Bbb N$.

Comment: for n=3 we get (0,3), here f(0) =0, f(1) =3?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130318/discussion-between-henno-brandsma-and-user4567).

Comment: check this my edit and understanding.

Comment: @User4567 I believe the edit is not needed...

Answer (score 0):

After understanding of @Henno Brandsma's answer I have created one **Example** for better understanding.

More precisely $2(n+1)−1=2n+1$ elements in $S$ for each $n.$
The max could be $f(0)$ in $n+1$ ways$, n+1$ ways for it to be $f(1)$ and $−1$ for the constant map that's counted doubly.

For example to get maximum value $n=3.$

**Case:1** If max is $f(0)$, we know that $(0,3)$ is in the map and $f(1)$ can be $0,1,2,3.$Then the elements of $S$ are $\{(0,3),(1,0)\},$$\{(0,3),(1,1)\},$$\{(0,3),(1,2)\},$$\{(0,3),(1,3)\}.$ are map to same image $3$ in $\mathbb{N}$ because every element  $max(f(0),f(1))$ is $3.$ Here number of elements $=4.$

**Case:2** If max is $f(1)$, we know that $(1,3)$ is in the map and $f(0)$ can be $0,1,2,3.$Then the elements of $S$ are $\{(0,0),(1,3)\},$$\{(0,1),(1,3)\},$$\{(0,2),(1,3)\},$$\{(0,3),(1,3)\}.$ are map to same image $3$ in $\mathbb{N}$ because every element  $max(f(0),f(1))$ is $3.$Here number of elements $=4.$

But we count $\{(0,3),(1,3)\}$ doubly, we should remove this.
So $7 = 2n+1$ elements in $S$ maps to element $3$ in $\mathbb{N}.$